# How to check cascade and shape predictor is in file same directory?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I'm Using Raspberry pi 3 in opencv python environment but getting this error. Is there an app to open .xml and .dat file in raspberry pi 3?

`: error: the following arguments are required: -c/--cascade, -p/--shape-predictor`

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-c", "--cascade", required=True, help = "path to where the face cascade resides")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--shape-predictor", required=True, help="path to facial landmark predictor")
ap.add_argument("-a", "--alarm", type=int, default=0, help="boolean used to indicate if TrafficHat should be used")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```